# Database design - Help desk application

Tags: c#, database-design, application-design

I can't decide whether to keep the help desk application in the same database as the rest of the corporate applications or completely separate it.

The help desk application can log support request from a phone call, email, website.

We can get questions sent to us from registered customers and non-registered customers.

The only reason to keep the help desk application in the same database is so that we can share the user base. But then again we can have the user create a new account for support or sync the user accounts with the help desk application.

If we separate the help desk application, our database backup will be smaller. Or we can just keep the help desk application in the same database, which makes development/integration a lot easier overall, having only one database to backup. (Maybe larger but still one database with everything.)

What to do?

Comment: Suppose you put the helpdesk database in the corporate applications database.  If the user is calling the helpdesk to report that the corporate application database server has melted down and is lying in a puddle of bits in the middle of the server room, how do you plan to enter his ticket?

Comment: ahh, good point. Well in this case, we cant provide support so thats bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a subjective answer, but I would keep the help desk system as a separate entity, unless there is a good business reason to use the same user base.

This is mostly based on what I've seen in professional helpdesk call logging/ticket software, but I do have another compelling reason - security - logic is as follows:

Generally, a helpdesk ticketing system generally needs less sensitive information than other business system (accounting, shopping, CRM, etc).  Your technicians will likely need to know how to contact a customer, but probably won't need to store full addresses, birth dates, etc.  All of the following is based on an assumption - that your existing customer data contains sensitive or personally identifiable data that would not be needed by your ticketing system.

- Principle 1: Reducing the attack surface area by limiting the stored data.  Generally, I subscribe to the principle that you should ONLY collect the data you absolutely need.  Having less sensitive information available means less that an attacker can steal.
- Principle 2: Reducing the surface area by minimizing avenues of attack into existing sensitive data.  Assuming you already have a large user base, and assuming that you're already storing potentially useful data about your customers, adding another application with hooks into that data is just adding further avenues of attack into the existing customer base.  This leads me to...
- Principle 3: Least privilege.  The user you set up for the helpdesk software database should have access ONLY to the data absolutely needed by your helpdesk analysts.  Accomplishing this is easier if you design your database with a specific set of  needs in mind.  It's a lot more difficult from a maintenance standpoint to have to set up views and stored procedures over sensitive data in order to only allow access to the non-sensitive data than it is to have a database designed to have only the data that you need.

Of course, I may be over-thinking it.  And there are other compelling reasons for going either route.  I'm just trying to give you something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely be a subjective answer based upon your environment.  You have to weigh the benefits/drawbacks of one choice with the benefits/drawbacks of the other choice.  However, my opinion would be that the best benefits will be found in separating the two databases.  I really don't like to have one database with two purposes.  Instead look to create a database with one purpose only.  Here are the benefits I see to doing this:

- Portability - if you decide to move the helpdesk to a different server, you can without issue.  The same is true if you want to move the corporate database somewhere else
- Separation of concerns - each database is designed for its own purpose.  The security of one won't interfere with the security of the other.
- Backup policies - Currently, you can only have one backup policy for both systems since they are in the same database.  If you split them, you could back up one more often than the other (and the backup would be smaller/faster).

The drawbacks I see (not being able to access the corporate data as easily) actually come out as a positive in my mind.  Accessing the data from the corporate database sounds good but it can be a security issue (also a maintainability issue).  Instead, this way you can limit how much access (and what type of access) is granted to the helpdesk system.  Databases can access each other fairly easily so it won't be that inconvenient and it will allow you to add a nice security barrier between your corporate data and your helpdesk data.